# How to make a member list with database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

How do I make a member list with PHP and MySQL?

I have user accounts, login and that stuff. How do I make a page that shows all the members?

I can provide code!

Comment: use a loop with a WHERE clause and possibly sessions, this being a shot in the dark answer; you can take it from there.

Comment: It would be nice to see what it was that you tried in order to have resolved this yourself, which would have shown us that you did research this before posting the question. 
When you try, you also learn. If someone just gives you an answer/solution, it would have all been for nothing and I say this for the/your future. 
You can then edit your post to contain something that may have failed; even that shows an effort on your part. Remember, we're always glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: Your question is not clear. You have not included any code or query snippet. I will try my best to answer your question.

As per my knowledge I think your users are nothing but the members. Just write a query to pull all the users from the users table and display.

NOTE : I will use mysqli_* function without any escaping please help yourself.

```
<?php

include_once 'db_connect.php'; /Line to include the database connection file, which had $link as resource */

$membersQuery = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users");
$members = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($membersQuery) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($membersQuery)){
        $members[] = $row; //Get all the members row by row and store in $members array
    }
}
?>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?
        if(count($members) > 0){
            foreach($members as $member){
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $member['firstname']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Even while looping in table you can use the following command

```
<tbody>
    <?
    if(mysqli_num_rows($membersQuery) > 0){
        while($member = mysqli_fetch_assoc($membersQuery)){
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $member['firstname']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
</tbody>
```